# Can anyone help identify the era or other specifics of this Air Force jacket?

Tags: united-states, military, identification

Thrifted a few years ago and haven't been able to determine anything about it in that time. I would like to have enough information to at least speculate on the rank and/or military activity of the person who originally owned it, assuming it's actually a genuine air force jacket and not related to Boy Scouts or something.

[image: image of leather jacket]

Entire outside of jacket is weathered. Circular patch on front is a red maple leaf with a spade and (maybe) a skull inside, I believe the long rectangular patch underneath says "AMERICAN AVIATOR", and on other side are flag patches (USA, Canada, UK, Italy, and Australia(?)).

Back of jacket says "AIR FORCE" and "VICTOIRE". I can't make out the last line on the ribbon underneath.

[image: Ace of spades patch]

This ace of spades patch is on the right arm, same side as the maple leaf.

Additionally, the jacket's tag includes "Made in Korea" and the inside lining appears just slightly greener in real life than it does in the picture.

[Here](https://ibb.co/album/kSs1va) are bigger pictures / details that might help.

Comment: It does not look to me to be a genuine piece of military gear so much as something made to be sold to  people with a certain fashion taste.

Comment: That's definitely not an air force jacket. No military clothing will have decorations imprinted on the liner. Only washing instructions.

Comment: If the inside looks that clean and the outside that weathered, there certainly was no living, breathing, sweating person inside the jacket while it was weathered. This was made to look this way.

Answer (score 3):

I believe it was manufactured to be that style,   An actual flight jacket wouldn't have a design with an airman posing with his hand in his pocket and something slung over his shoulder.   A bunch of similar jackets [here](http://www.mypilotstore.com/MyPilotStore/secp/190?qryrmv=1&utm_source=bing&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=1-35&keyword=flight%20jackets).

Comment: Hi Tad Siskiyou and welcome to History SE. This looks like a good start, but expanding on your answer would improve it.